# How to email multiple receiver with python?

Tags: php, python, wordpress, email

I have a php script to fetch user email address from my wordpress site database.
The php script as follow

```
$sql = "SELECT user_email FROM wp_users";
$addr = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($addr)){
        printf ("%s\n", $row["user_email"]);
}
```

The output will look like this

> abcd@gmail.com
>
> ggyy@gmail.com

In my python code i use `urllib2` to read the php and the python snippet look like this

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.168/useremail.php')
status = response.read()

fromaddr = "testing123@gmail.com"
toaddr = status
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr)
```

In this case, the email always sent to the first email address only despite there are several email address retrieve from the php script.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Sorry to say that I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: why mix python and PHP here? use one or the other

Comment: @e4c5 I have a script running in python, when event triggered, it send email to notify client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendmail()` needs a list of mail addresses. So, you'll need to build that list with the response of urllib2.

Use [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines) to return a list of the lines in the string.

i.e. :

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.168/useremail.php')
status = response.read()

mail_list = status.splitlines() # split the response in a list 

print mail_list
# ['john@doe.tld', 'smyth@noon.tld', 'arthur@excalibur.tld', 'george@dada.tld']

# then send the mails    
fromaddr = "testing123@gmail.com"
server.sendmail(fromaddr, mail_list)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I get this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'.` I found my mail_list is something like this,`['abc@gmail.com', 'efg@gmail.com', ' ']` . There is an empty quote due to the line break in my php printf. Do you have any idea on this error?

Comment: Hi, i have figure out what problem is going on, since i imported `email.MTMEText` into my script, it set up the "To:" header. And it must be single string. In that part, i have to code like `msg['To']=','.join(mail_list).` So your `splitlines()` method work like a charm